# Object property with matching value jquery js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json file with players names on it as properties and the values are yes and no. I'm trying to add one to count every time the (Property = 'yes), player plays.

**Here an example of the json file**

> {"Wojciech Szczesny":"yes","Lukasz Fabianski":"no","Emiliano Viviano":"no","Olivier Giroud":"yes","Per Mertesacker":"yes","Bacary Sagna":"yes","Laurent Koscielny":"no","Santi Cazorla":"yes","Mikel Arteta":"yes","Mesut \u00d6zil":"no","Kieran Gibbs":"yes","Aaron Ramsey":"no","Jack Wilshere":"no","Mathieu Flamini":"yes","Tomas Rosicky":"yes","Lukas Podolski":"yes","Nacho Monreal":"no","Theo Walcott":"no","Thomas Vermaelen":"yes","Carl Jenkinson":"no","Alex Oxlade-Chamberlain":"no","Serge Gnabry":"no","Kim Kallstrom":"no","Nicklas Bendtner":"no","Abou Diaby":"no","Park Chu-Young":"no","Emmanuel Frimpong":"no","Yaya Sanogo":"no","Ryo Miyaichi":"no","Hector Bellerin":"no","Chuba Akpom":"no","Isaac Hayden":"no","Gideon Zelalem":"no","Home":"home","Results":"draw"}

**And here my Jquery code**

```
var count = 0;
    $.ajax({
        url:'ars.json',
        dataType:'json',
        cache: true,
  success: function(data) {
    $(data).each(function(index, value){
        if(Object.getOwnPropertyNames (value) == 'yes'){
            count++;
        }else{

        }
    });
    console.log(count);
}
```

Comment: Just `value == 'yes'`???

Comment: See also [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call): You're logging `count` before it will get incremented.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsbin.com/CountSamePropertyValues/1/edit?js,console,output

```
var count = 0;
$.ajax({
  url:'ars.json',
  dataType:'json',
  cache: true,
  success: function(data) {
    for(var k in data){
      if(data.hasOwnProperty(k) && data[k]=="yes"){
         count++;
      }
    }
    console.log(count); // 11
  }
});
```

Comment: I also just receive zero

Comment: @user3210416 have you tried to just hit the `RUN WITH JS` button in my example? Or to just simply use my suggestion in your project?

Answer (score 1):

As I got it you want to count the properties with value 'yes'...
You did two mistakes - which made your code completely wrong:
1. You are using Object instead of this inside the loop, of course Object has no any of the properties you are looking for...
2. $(data).each runs only once as data is not an array but a single object
Now for the right code:

```
success: function(data) {
  var count = 0;
  for(value in data) {
    if(data[value] == 'yes') {
      count++;
    } else {
      //
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var v = {"Wojciech Szczesny":"yes","Lukasz Fabianski":"no","Emiliano Viviano":"no","Olivier Giroud":"yes","Per Mertesacker":"yes","Bacary Sagna":"yes","Laurent Koscielny":"no","Santi Cazorla":"yes","Mikel Arteta":"yes","Mesut \u00d6zil":"no","Kieran Gibbs":"yes","Aaron Ramsey":"no","Jack Wilshere":"no","Mathieu Flamini":"yes","Tomas Rosicky":"yes","Lukas Podolski":"yes","Nacho Monreal":"no","Theo Walcott":"no","Thomas Vermaelen":"yes","Carl Jenkinson":"no","Alex Oxlade-Chamberlain":"no","Serge Gnabry":"no","Kim Kallstrom":"no","Nicklas Bendtner":"no","Abou Diaby":"no","Park Chu-Young":"no","Emmanuel Frimpong":"no","Yaya Sanogo":"no","Ryo Miyaichi":"no","Hector Bellerin":"no","Chuba Akpom":"no","Isaac Hayden":"no","Gideon Zelalem":"no","Home":"home","Results":"draw"};

var count = 0;
$.each(v, function(k,v) {
    if (v == "yes") count++;
});

console.log(count);
```

## **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WcRLw/)**

**In your case:**

```
var count = 0;
$.ajax({
        url: 'ars.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: true,
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                if (value == "yes") count++;
            });
            console.log(count);
        }
});
```

Comment: @user3210416 what are the values of `index` and `data` when you `console.log` them in the loop?

Comment: What do you mean? Add a console.log(index, value) to `$.each()`

Comment: Sorry about that I mean the values shows just like in the example and then shows the count equalling to zero